# How do I get the max timestamp in each row with NaT values?

Tags: python, pandas, databricks, azure-databricks

First of all I am working with Databricks 11.3 with Python 3.9.5 so that might make a difference as I've come to realize in the past.

For each row I need to get the latest timestamp but as soon as I introduce NaT values I get NaN for each row as the output. When I tried it with dummy data to post on here, everything works fine like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": [pd.datetime(1900, 2, 1), pd.datetime(1950, 2, 1), pd.datetime(2000, 2, 1)],
        "col2": [pd.datetime(1900, 1, 1), pd.datetime(1950, 1, 1), pd.datetime(2000, 1, 1)],
    },
    columns=["col1", "col2"],
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": [pd.datetime(1900, 2, 1), pd.datetime(1950, 2, 1), pd.datetime(2000, 2, 1)],
        "col2": [pd.NaT, pd.datetime(1950, 1, 1), pd.datetime(2000, 1, 1)],
    },
    columns=["col1", "col2"],
)
df1['time_max'] = df1.max(axis=1)
df2['time_max'] = df2.max(axis=1)
```

```
df1:

col1    col2    time_max
0   1900-02-01  1900-01-01  1900-02-01
1   1950-02-01  1950-01-01  1950-02-01
2   2000-02-01  2000-01-01  2000-02-01
```

```
df2: 

    col1    col2    time_max
0   1900-02-01  NaT 1900-02-01
1   1950-02-01  1950-01-01  1950-02-01
2   2000-02-01  2000-01-01  2000-02-01
```

As soon as I apply the same logit to my actual data, everything works fine up to the point the first NaT is introduced. The first 10 rows work fine, with the 11th row added, the whole column becomes NaN.

First 10 rows:

```
x['max_time'] = x.loc[:, ['last_a', 'last_b']].max(axis=1)
x

    last_a  last_b  last_c  max_time
0   2023-09-06 10:24:47.386000+00:00    2023-09-10 21:56:46.704120800+00:00 2023-09-10T21:56:46.7041208Z    2023-09-10 21:56:46.704120800+00:00
1   2023-09-06 11:09:52.037000+00:00    2023-09-11 04:19:59.189798400+00:00 2023-09-11T04:19:59.1897984Z    2023-09-11 04:19:59.189798400+00:00
2   2023-09-06 11:09:52.037000+00:00    2023-09-11 04:19:59.189798400+00:00 2023-09-11T04:19:59.1897984Z    2023-09-11 04:19:59.189798400+00:00
3   2023-09-06 07:27:13.691000+00:00    2023-09-11 06:40:45.243917400+00:00 2023-09-11T06:40:45.2439174Z    2023-09-11 06:40:45.243917400+00:00
4   2023-09-06 07:27:13.691000+00:00    2023-09-11 06:40:45.243917400+00:00 2023-09-11T06:40:45.2439174Z    2023-09-11 06:40:45.243917400+00:00
5   2023-09-06 10:42:37.268000+00:00    2023-09-11 06:20:22.268724500+00:00 2023-09-11T06:20:22.2687245Z    2023-09-11 06:20:22.268724500+00:00
6   2023-05-09 09:14:40.220000+00:00    2023-06-06 05:19:05.132792200+00:00 2023-06-06T05:19:05.1327922Z    2023-06-06 05:19:05.132792200+00:00
7   2023-09-06 07:56:21.199000+00:00    2023-09-11 04:58:10.908393+00:00    2023-09-11T04:58:10.908393Z 2023-09-11 04:58:10.908393+00:00
8   2023-09-06 07:56:21.199000+00:00    2023-09-11 04:58:10.908393+00:00    2023-09-11T04:58:10.908393Z 2023-09-11 04:58:10.908393+00:00
9   2023-08-15 20:07:25.868000+00:00    2023-09-11 05:01:35.413615700+00:00 2023-09-11T05:01:35.4136157Z    2023-09-11 05:01:35.413615700+00:00
```

first 11 rows:

```
x['max_time'] = x.loc[:, ['last_a', 'last_b']].max(axis=1)
x

last_a  last_b  last_c  max_time
0   2023-09-06 10:24:47.386000+00:00    2023-09-10 21:56:46.704120800+00:00 2023-09-10T21:56:46.7041208Z    NaN
1   2023-09-06 11:09:52.037000+00:00    2023-09-11 04:19:59.189798400+00:00 2023-09-11T04:19:59.1897984Z    NaN
2   2023-09-06 11:09:52.037000+00:00    2023-09-11 04:19:59.189798400+00:00 2023-09-11T04:19:59.1897984Z    NaN
3   2023-09-06 07:27:13.691000+00:00    2023-09-11 06:40:45.243917400+00:00 2023-09-11T06:40:45.2439174Z    NaN
4   2023-09-06 07:27:13.691000+00:00    2023-09-11 06:40:45.243917400+00:00 2023-09-11T06:40:45.2439174Z    NaN
5   2023-09-06 10:42:37.268000+00:00    2023-09-11 06:20:22.268724500+00:00 2023-09-11T06:20:22.2687245Z    NaN
6   2023-05-09 09:14:40.220000+00:00    2023-06-06 05:19:05.132792200+00:00 2023-06-06T05:19:05.1327922Z    NaN
7   2023-09-06 07:56:21.199000+00:00    2023-09-11 04:58:10.908393+00:00    2023-09-11T04:58:10.908393Z NaN
8   2023-09-06 07:56:21.199000+00:00    2023-09-11 04:58:10.908393+00:00    2023-09-11T04:58:10.908393Z NaN
9   2023-08-15 20:07:25.868000+00:00    2023-09-11 05:01:35.413615700+00:00 2023-09-11T05:01:35.4136157Z    NaN
10  2023-08-15 20:07:25.868000+00:00    NaT None    NaN
```

Reproducible Code:

```
y = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    'last_a': ['2023-09-06 10:24:47.386000+00:00', '2023-09-06 11:09:52.037000+00:00', '2023-09-06 11:09:52.037000+00:00', '2023-09-06 07:27:13.691000+00:00'],
    'last_b': ['2023-09-10 21:56:46.704120800+00:00', '2023-09-11 04:19:59.189798400+00:00', '2023-09-11 04:19:59.189798400+00:00', None]
    },
    columns=['last_a', 'last_b']
)

# y = y.loc[0:2]

y['last_a'] = pd.to_datetime(y['last_a'],format= '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
y['last_b'] = pd.to_datetime(y['last_b'],format= '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
y['last_max'] = y.max(axis=1)
y
```

I get different results whether I include this `y = y.loc[0:2]` line or not.

How do I fix this? The timestamps were converted from text using `pd.to_datetime()`

Thanks in advance!
Cheers

Comment: Double check your conversion, this is not reproducible. You must have non-datetime data. What is the output of `df.dtypes`? Can you run `df = df.apply(pd.to_datetime)`?

Comment: One column was of type object. I fixed that and remove the case from my question. The NaT issue still remains. Now all three columns are of type datetime64[ns, UTC] max_time is of type float64 for some reason.

Comment: Can you provide **code** to set up a reproducible example? It works fine for me

Comment: I added one that creates NaNs or not depending on NaT values that works on my Databricks.

Comment: It works fine for me (pandas 2.1.0) and I have no NaT in the max column, (I just modified your code to remove the custom format in `to_datetime`)

Comment: I have the same issue with or without the format. I think it might have something to die with my Databricks version. Any other way to implement the same outcome?

Comment: since you want the `max` date, you could `fillna` with a very old date to ensure not being the max?

Comment: It works if I use `y.apply(max, axis=1)` instead. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import display
df = pd.DataFrame({
'col1': [pd.Timestamp('2021-01-01'), pd.Timestamp('2021-01-02'), pd.NaT],
'col2': [pd.Timestamp('2021-01-03'), pd.NaT, pd.Timestamp('2021-01-04')]
})
df = df.fillna(pd.Timestamp('1900-01-01'))
df['max_time'] = df[['col1', 'col2']].max(axis=1)
df['max_time'] = np.where(df['max_time'] == pd.Timestamp('1900-01-01'), pd.NaT, df['max_time'])
display(df)
```

[image]

In the above code i have replaced the **NaT** values with a default value `(pd.Timestamp('1900-01-01'))` using `fillna`.

calculated the maximum timestamp for the '**col1**' and '**col2**' columns using **max(axis=1)** and store the result in a new '**max_time**' column.

used **np.where** to replace the default value **(pd.Timestamp('1900-01-01'))** with **NaT** where appropriate in the '**max_time**' column.

Comment: can you approximate the nat by interpolating surrounding date

Comment: Unfortunately `fillna` is also behaving weirdly in my Databricks version but thanks for your help nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

It works if I use `y.apply(max, axis=1)` instead of `y.max(axis=1)`.

I still have no idea why Databricks works differently but the fix is enough for now.